# jQuery UI Sortable, event for mouse button released?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have the following bit of jQuery:

```
$('.blah').sortable({
    items:'.item',
    helper:'clone',
    revert:true,
    stop:function(event,ui){
        console.log('stopped');
    }
});
```

When I drag the items somewhere "bad" (where they cant be sorted, e.g. outside of the sortable area) within this sortable, the clone reverts back to its last good place inside the sortable. When this animation is complete, the stop function fires off 'stopped'.

Is there an event I can use which fires off as soon as the mouse button is released? (Or before this reverting animation begins?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this so when an item is dragged, it adds a mouseup event, when it is then dropped again, the function fires and then the listener is deactivated.

```
$('.blah').sortable({
    items:'.item',
    helper:'clone',
    revert:true,
    stop:function(event,ui){
        console.log('stopped');
        $('.ui-draggable').off('mouseup');
    }
    start:function(e,ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable').on('mouseup', function() {
              console.log('drop'); 
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: so basically, there is no event for the user stops dragging, i have to manually detect it myself?

Comment: Nothing as far as I can see from the API, seems like an oversight on jQuery's part.

Answer (score 0):

May be out event can help you for this :

```
$('.blah').sortable({
items:'.item',
helper:'clone',
revert:true,
stop:function(event,ui){
    console.log('stopped');
},
out: function( event, ui ) { alert("before stopped");} });
```

Comment: this event fires off, not only when an item has left the sortable area, but also when an item has been dropped (even if its dropped within the sortable area). seems bugged and erratic.